# How to add range axis label in a Stacked barchart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to know how to add range axis label in a Stacked Bar chart.The below image shows a stacked bar chart.I do not want the range axis line to be displayed.I have been able to remove the range axis line ,but along with it the range axis label i.e Revenue($M) is also removed.

Can anyone please help me with this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyuMZ.png

I want Revenue($M) to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would hide the axis line using the [setAxisLineVisible()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setAxisLineVisible%28boolean%29) method:

```
ValueAxis yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
```

I'm guessing that you did something else if the axis label disappeared also.

Comment: ya your right i used yAxis.setVisible(false),which made the yaxis line and label disappear.After using yAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false) the line disappeared,but i dont want the range values also to display,i only want the label to be displayed.

Comment: Hey i did get the answer.Thank you David for your help.

Comment: setTickLabelsVisible(false)